# Generate BTC Private key from user string input

Tags: private-key, address-generation, private-key-import, c#, nbitcoin

I am looking to generate a Bitcoin Address from an user input text (like the good old days Brainwallet).
User input a "Text string" and based on this text string generate the corresponding Bitcoin Address. My google search lead me to NBitcoin and to this post: [Generate address of 'private key' from user input](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100121/generate-address-of-private-key-from-user-input)

The user SVVC asked the same question got a reply from Prayank with a little code snippet but here I am stuck because the snippet didn't work and the Debugger gave me an Exception Unhandled "System.FormatException: 'Invalid hash of the base 58 string"

Anyone have an idea?

Here is my code in VisualBasic .Net with NBitcoin

```
Dim pk As String = "LoveIsTheKey"
Dim bitcoinPrivateKey = New BitcoinSecret(pk, Network.Main)
Dim legacy_address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy)
MessageBox.Show("Legacy Address : " + legacy_address.ToString)
```

Thanks guys

Comment: *”Like the good old days Brainwallet”* - you mean when users were encouraged to create inherently insecure wallets, leading to an irrecoverable loss of funds? I assume that you won’t be taking the user input as the sole source of entropy for privkey generation?

Comment: There will be no user to my program I just want to make it for myself for research purposes.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

i upload a github repository. it takes text as input to generate private key, public key and segwit/bech32 address.

https://github.com/drParadox312/Bitcoin_Key_Generator_From_Text_Input

Answer (score 0):

The code works if you enter any private key in [WIF format](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/wif):

1. Copy private key for an address from Electrum(testnet)

[image: electrum-privatekey]

2. Run the below code

   ```
   using System;
   using NBitcoin;

   namespace NPrivKeyAdd
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter private key:");
               string private_key = Console.ReadLine();
               var bitcoinPrivateKey = new BitcoinSecret(private_key, Network.TestNet);

               var legacy_address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy);
               var segwitp2sh_address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.SegwitP2SH);
               var nativesegwit_address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Segwit);

               Console.WriteLine("Private Key :" + bitcoinPrivateKey);
               Console.WriteLine("Legacy Address :" + legacy_address);
               Console.WriteLine("Segwit-P2SH Address :" + segwitp2sh_address);
               Console.WriteLine("Bech32 Address :" + nativesegwit_address);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   [image: addresses]

If you want to experiment with random strings that can be used to spend bitcoin, this is an interesting example in which knowing birth date is equivalent to private key:

https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/other_types_of_ownership/arbitrary

Comment: Ok, but how I can enter simply a TextString to be converted to a WIF Key?
I didn't understand the sample with the BirthDay.